# Move logical volume to a new physical disk

Tags: linux, lvm

I have three logical volumes in a single volume group using a single physical volume (the whole existing disk /dev/sda).

I now want to move one of those logical volumes to a new, faster disk, i.e., going from:

```
/dev/sda
    |-vg0-root → mounted to /
    |-vg0-foo  → mounted to /foo
    |-vg0-bar  → mounted to /bar
```

to:

```
/dev/sda
    |-vg0-root → mounted to /
    |-vg0-foo →  mounted to /foo

/dev/sdb
    |-vg1-bar  → mounted to /bar
```

From what I understand I cannot use `pvmove` or `vgsplit` because there's only one physical volume in the existing volume group.

What's a good approach to achieve this (preferably online, creating a new volume group for the new disk is not a requirement)?

Comment: I did check the many similar questions, but as far as I understand, those don't describe my situation. Bonus question: Is using a whole disk as physical volume a bad idea per se? It seems this decision made the solution much harder in my case.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason you don't want to add your new physical disk as a physical volume to the existing volume group?

Comment: Not at all. If it makes things easier, the new disk can be part of vg0 as well.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One volume group solution:

```
 pvcreate /dev/sdb
 vgextend vg0 /dev/sdb
 pvmove -n /dev/vg0/bar /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

Two volume group solution:

```
 pvcreate /dev/sdb
 vgcreate vg1 /dev/sdb
 lvcreate -l100%FREE vg1
 mkfs -t ext4 /dev/vg1/lvol1
 mount /dev/vg1/lvol1 /mnt
```

Now difficult part, all activities MUST stop on `/bar`:

```
 cd /mnt ; ( cd /bar ; tar cf - * ) | tar xf -
 cd /
 umount /mnt
 mount /dev/vg1/lvol1 /bar
```

where

- `pvcreate` erase all data on disk (and prepare for LVM)
- `lvcreate` sould create a logical volume lvol1, you specify lv name with `-n bar`
- I use HP-UX syntax for lv, you might have to use `/dev/mapper/myvg-mylv` syntax

Once you have verified data are OK, in new place:

- you can safely delete old `/bar`
- edit `/etc/fstab` to use new `/bar`

Comment: Wow, seems I completely misread the `pvmove` man page. In that case I'll obviously settle for the one volume group solution. :)

Comment: Actually, one could use `vgsplit` after `pvmove` to achieve the two volume group solution a bit easier (however, the logical volume still needs to be deactivated using `lvchange`).

Comment: The usefulness of "pvmove" is a very good reason to use a single VG instead of multiple VGs.

Comment: It seems like `vgreduce` can then be used to remove the old volume if that is the requirement (It wasn't for the specific question, but a question asking about moving all volumes would likely be marked a duplicate)

Comment: My current experience is that in the single vg solution, `pvmove` requires an `-n` flag to specify the logical volume. Or it says a `Physical volume /dev/vg0/bar not found
  Run \`pvmove --help' for more information.` error message. The man page says the same. May I insert it into the post?

Comment: @peterh feel free.

Comment: In my case, using the "One volume group" method, I wanted to extend the logical volume to the new available space, and since it was and ext4 file system, I could run `lvextend -r vg0/bar /dev/sdb` to accomplish this.

Comment: warning: tar with `*` might skip hidden (dot) files. I prefer the following line: `tar cC /bar . | tar xC /mnt`